# Passing variable in jq to filter with select fails

Tags: jq

When I do this:

```
$ jq -cr '.arr[]|select(.id==-1)|.desc' <<<$'{"arr":[{"id":-1,"desc":"foo"},{"id":100}]}'
foo
```

works as expected.

But if I try to pass a variable in place of the index:

```
$ lookup=-1; jq -cr --arg l "$lookup" '.arr[]|select(.id==$l)|.desc' <<<$'{"arr":[{"id":-1,"desc":"foo"},{"id":100}]}'
no output
```

Doesn't produce output this time.

How to fix this so that it works with shell variable `lookup`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `--argjson` instead of `--arg`.

`--arg l "$lookup"` makes `$l` a string. With `--argjson l "$lookup"` it is interpreted as JSON, a number in this case, just as was `1` in `.id==-1`, your working example.

Or do an additional operation to use the `tonumber` flag to `$l`, indicating that you want the operation on a numeric equivalent of the string value passed. i.e. `($l|tonumber)`